# Using - in REGEX mySQL query

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to create a query in **mySQL**, so that I can match:

```
a-z
0-9
_ 
-
.
/
```

Thus far, I have:

```
UPDATE Errors SET been_checked = 1 WHERE binary(request) REGEXP "^[a-z0-9_./]+$" AND been_checked = 0
```

This works, but I don't have the - as one of the characters. So, I'm trying:

```
UPDATE Errors SET been_checked = 1 WHERE binary(request) REGEXP "^[a-z0-9_-./]+$" AND been_checked = 0
```

...but this gives me an error:

> Error: Could not execute query: Failed to execute query: 'UPDATE
>   Errors SET been_checked = 1 WHERE binary(request) REGEXP
>   "^[a-z0-9_-./]+$" AND been_checked = 0': Got error 'invalid
>   character range' from regexp

I've tried using `\-` , but that doesn't work either.

How do I use `-` as part of the matching string?

Thanks

Comment: Put it at start or end of the character class `[-a-z0-9_./]`

Comment: @bobblebubble - thanks, that did the trick :) Please mark it as an answer, and I'll accept when I'm able to :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the hyphen at start or end of your character class or escape it.

```
[-a-z0-9_./]
```

Else the hyphen indicates a [character range](http://regexone.com/lesson/character_ranges) inside a class.